# Writing specs in flow: how to stub a method in mocha?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, flowtype

Class A has a read-only property `b`, `b` has method `c`, in A#`methodF`, there's a statement:

`const v = await this.b.c();`

In specs for A#`methodF`, I'd like to stub `c`:

`a.b.c = sinon.stub().resolves({myDesiredResult})`
(where `a` is an instance of `A`)

but `flow check` gives:

> Cannot assign sinon.stub().resolves(...) to
>   a.b.c because property c
>   is not writable.

Question: how can I make `c` return the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not using sinon.stub correctly. You are trying to set a.b.c to a new value (the stub) when you really want to assign the stub to a new variable. The syntax for sinon.stub is this ([docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.1/stubs/)):

`var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method");`

So in your case:

`var cStub = sinon.stub(a.b, "c").resolves({myDesiredResult})`